# opencv higher precision for floats / doubles

Tags: c++, opencv, double, floating-point-precision

I'm trying to represent something like 1.0e+10 * 5.1901 in C++ opencv. I have been using CV_64F. I was wondering what is of a higher precision? I reckon that perhaps double will be better - however, how do I do something like `Mat X = Mat::zeros(ydim, 1, CV_64F)` and replace `CV_64F` with `double` or anything that has higher precision? (X is being changed later on ofcourse which is why I'm having this problem).

The matrix X is not an image - it is a matrix.

Comment: `CV_64F` is an enum that instructs OpenCV to create the matrix with element type `double`. Thus, you are already using the highest resolution possible, unless you plan to develop your own customized numerical type.

Comment: Well can this : `1.0e+10 * 5.1901` be represented with CV_64F?

Comment: Yes, a double (CV_64f) can represent that product.

Comment: Even a `float` has no problems with that product (less than 6 digits, less than 1e+38)